# How to simulate a paste in a file

Tags: java

How can I simulate a paste in a file using java?
I have this code

```
Desktop().getDesktop().open(new File("pathOfTheFile"));
File file = new File(pathOfTheFile);
file.createNewFile()
Desktop().getDesktop().open(file);
```

It is in a context of automated tests. I copied a text from the screen which works perfectly(it is hided from the code below) and then I opened a directory and created the file *file*. In the next step, I didn't find a way to paste it in the file *file* that is opened.

Comment: How is it related to `Selenium`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `selenium`.

Let's break your problem into steps:-

1. Copy text data from clipboard
2. Paste data in the newly created file.

I would have created two methods to handle this like below-

```
public  String getClipBoardData(){
    try {
        return (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and

```
public void writeInFile(String data){
    try{
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("path-to-your-file");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        out.write(data);
        out.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped you.

Comment: @Amol I'm also looking for the same..So implemented as you suggested, but getting one HeadlessException in getClipBoardData(). Have any idea?